# Killing long-running native code on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, kill-process

How can I immediately abandon a long-running computation in native code (in C) on Android when the user presses a Cancel button, without inserting cancellation checks?

To explain the constraints:

- This native code is too complex to insert sufficient cancellation checks or progress information[1], so the process must be forcibly killed.
- The Android app's UI must remain running (hence a separate process) to let the user conveniently retry with different parameters.
- There's no need to support more than one such computation at a time.

I'm well aware that the general position on process lifecycle on Android is that you must let the platform manage it for you. Nonetheless, I want to get as close to the above requirement as possible with as few unsupported operations as possible.

I have a solution below but I'm hoping there's a better one. For example if you split a service into an extra process using the [android:process attribute](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#proc) on a `<service>`, and one thread of that goes into a deep JNI call, is there a way to immediately kill such a process, or exit it from within, without causing the runtime to treat it as an unexpected crash?

---

[1] I have tried cancellation checks. It's over 70,000 SLOC (3.1 MB) of C whose memory allocations and control flow are complex; it was not written with interruptibility in mind. That way lies double-`free()` and inscrutable crashes in subsequent operation.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I currently do:

- In [build.gradle](https://github.com/chrisboyle/sgtpuzzles/blob/2015-07-10-2308-aa1a937/app/build.gradle#L90): compile a native-only executable, as if for command-line invocation.

  - Magic words to search for other people doing this are [ndk "BUILD_EXECUTABLE"](https://www.google.com/search?q=ndk+%22BUILD_EXECUTABLE%22).
  - This must be named as if it is a library, to persuade the build tools to include it and the package installer on devices to unpack it.
  - This is not yet achievable in the [Android Studio Preview NDK support](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview) and I'm really hoping the final release will leave this door open in some roundabout way.
- When [starting the process](https://github.com/chrisboyle/sgtpuzzles/blob/2015-07-10-2308-aa1a937/app/src/main/java/name/boyle/chris/sgtpuzzles/GamePlay.java#L798), copy it to a path where I can `chmod +x` it, do that, and `Runtime.exec()` it (I only need <1KB from stdout).
- To stop the process, just call `.destroy()` on it.

The supportedness of this is questionable: NDK docs talk about how [you can build an executable but it won't get installed](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/lollipop-mr1-release/docs/text/ANDROID-MK.text#23). Empirically, though, it has broad compatibility with mainstream Android devices between at least v2.1-5.1. It is deployed in a [widely-used app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=name.boyle.chris.sgtpuzzles) (100,000 downloads, ~47,000 active).

Environments where it fails, probably during the binary installation shenanigans above, include:

- [App Runtime for Chrome](https://github.com/chrisboyle/sgtpuzzles/issues/275)
- [Blackberry](https://github.com/chrisboyle/sgtpuzzles/issues/136)